# Time Machine API / Command-line scripts?

Tags: macos, timemachine

I need the reference, if it exists, to Time Machine's API or simply some commands that can change the disk in use with Time Machine and back!

I'd like the script I'm going to write to do the following:

Change from disk A to disk B
Force Time Machine backup
Change from disk B back to disk A

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I knew what to put there, it seems the file to edit is /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist.

You can achieve the correct configuration using "defaults write" to overwrite the relevant settings, although it seems like you have to modify the BackupAlias, which seems to be a hexdump of something I couldn't quite decipher. It does contain the path to my TimeMachine disk,  though.

The sanest solution would be to copy the original settings, and then swap files whenever needed.

Comment: This worked, but I found a third-party solution to be superior to Time Machine for the purpose of the problem.

Answer (score 9):

Lion added tmutil, a command line interface into Time Machine.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17759/what-tiny-thing-in-lion-makes-you-smile-or-has-caught-you-off-guard/18665#18665

Answer (score 1):

If AppleScript is fine with you have a look at [this post with script](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20080105135511764). It should serve as a basis for your own.

Comment: The solution doesn't appeal to me much, as I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be as complex as that just to swap a drive... I mean, right, it does work, and I could resort to that if I find absolutely nothing else...

Comment: Much of the complexity in that script is just checking whether the drive is available and doing the Growl notification. The actual logic to change drives isn’t too bad, and involves UI-scripting the Time Machine Preferences panel. While this is not an API, it is certainly the safe way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Apple time capsules include an 'archive' command that can back-up the time capsule disk to an external USB-attached disk.

Comment: Not sure, but since an archive takes several hours I don't think you would benefit much from having a command-line form.  But I like your thinking.

Answer (score 0):

This [Krypted.com blog post](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/mass-deploying-time-machine/) has a good list of the main command line use cases.

Also, if you are interested in anything Time Machine the place to start is the unofficial [pondini FAQ](http://pondini.org/TM/FAQ.html).